# Sum of column after autofilter vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to:
- Open a file **`"perpetual.xlsx"`**
- Filter a column based on a criteria
- Take sum of another column and enter it in my original file in another column. My original file is as shown in the picture below.
- Continue the loop from step 2 till the original file's last row.

[image]Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RowLast As Long
Dim tempLast As Long
tempLast = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim perporig As Workbook

'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(1, 9).Value = here
For i = 5 To tempLast
    Set perporig = Workbooks.Open("\\Etnfps02\vol1\DATA\Inventory\Daily tracking\perpetual.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
    With perporig.Sheets("perpetual")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A3:J" & RowLast).AutoFilter field:=1, criteria:=Range("B" & i).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(i, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Columns("H:H"))
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    perporig.Close savechanges:=False
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myperpetual").Activate
Next i
Cells(1, 9).Value = here
End Sub
```

The code only runs until line 9, i.e.: Set perporig = .... and after that it stops for some reason. The file "perpetual.xlsx" opens and the code stops. If I remove the apostrophe in line 6, the code doesn't seem to run at all.

EDITED CODE:
Thank you for your suggestions. Didn't know where to put my code, so here it is. Again, the code only runs until line 7, i.e.: Set perporig = .... and after that it stops for some reason. The file "perpetual.xlsx" opens and the code stops. If I remove the apostrophe in line 6, the code doesn't seem to run at all. Please help.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim RowLast As Long
Dim tempLast As Long
tempLast = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Dim perporig As Workbook
'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(1, 9).Value = "here"
Set perporig = Workbooks.Open("\\Etnfps02\vol1\DATA\Inventory\Daily tracking\perpetual.xlsx", UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
For i = 5 To tempLast
    With perporig.Sheets("perpetual")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        RowLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A3:J" & RowLast).AutoFilter field:=1, criteria:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(i, 2).Value
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Cells(i, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
Next
perporig.Close savechanges:=False
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("combine BOMs").Activate
Cells(1, 9).Value = "here"
End Sub
```

Comment: Yo uare opening the "perpetual.xlsx" for each row, this is overly heavy stuff. Open the application in an object and closes it out of the loop

Comment: remove "Next i" in the end of the loop, keep only the "Next" without the `I` counter

Comment: Also this is not your problem but it will be, Sum will ignore whether the row is hidden through the filter or not and include it in the output.  You need to look into the subtotal() function.  Or iterate yourself through the rows and test whether it is hidden or not and keep your own sum.

Comment: @Rogerio, tried removing the i, didn't help...

Comment: You should assign a value to `RowLast` before using it...

Comment: I jsut tried, not working..

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the Line 7 wont run is because you have not defined what 'here' is. If you want to put text in that cell you should end the line with = "here", so that that value is a string.

As the other commenter says. You should not open the workbook within a loop. First open the workbook and then do the loop operations with the book (perporig) opened.

Comment: Just realized, I had another file open which had it's own code, and was probably interfering. I closed it and not it enters the for loop, but it gives an error on line 12 (autofilter line). I get "application defined or object defined error."

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it, it was a simple mistake, in addition to everyone else's suggestions, I had mentioend criteria:= instead of criteria1:=
Stupid mistake.